# Arrow keys in iOS Safari how to handle them

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari, keyboard

My component handles the tab key on desktop and I want to do the same for mobile. In iOS' Safari there is a keyboard with arrow keys, but unfortunately I cannot find what event they fire. I've read some 4 years posts but at the time there was no solution for this problem.

**Question** How to handle arrow keys in Safari in iOS.

Focusout etc. does not suit my case as the component is very complex handling focusout contradicts other use cases of the component.

[image]

Comment: While on iOS it seems no KeyDown event is fired, there is still a FocusEvent when tabbing via the arrows from one form element to another.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but they are not unfortunately.

Comment: @Bemmu Yes but unfortunately it is too "broad' event for the component, the component can loose focus in many use case scenarios and some of them stand in the way of handling focusout.

Comment: Have you [seen this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22833373/989920)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes but that is solution for very particular problem, I would like the general solution to detect that these buttons were pressed.

Comment: Using `monitorEvents` in the iOS simulator, I concluded that they don't fire any events themselves, only `blur` and `focus` events are fired on the inputs.